# Django auth system: adding user to group via "invites"

Tags: django

I want to use the Django default auth system to manage users and groups. Is there an existing Django app/module that adds users to groups by invites? I.e. some existing user of the group sends an invite with a secret key in a URL, and another user that clicks on the URL joins the group.

I can write one, but figured I ask before doing that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will solve all your problems but do take a look at [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/). They have features to support user invitation and user groups.

Comment: Thanks, good pointer, but didn't see immediately if there was a module that just did invites and stuff, but I will investigate. Lots of other neat features though.